# Stack overflow for my code on Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stack-overflow

I have been writing solution to a problem on UVa Online Judge, and when testing my code on Visual Studio it gives the

> Unhandled exception at 0x01228249 in Light raods.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x00A02000).

message, which I do not understand, because I do not spot any error in the code itself.  Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<queue>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
#define MAX 1000000000
int m, n;
int main() {
    int aaa = 0;
    while (cin >> m >> n&&m != 0 && n != 0) {
        int totallength = 0;
        vector<pair<int, int>>neibs[200001];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int x, y, z;
            cin >> x >> y >> z;
            neibs[x].push_back(make_pair(y, z));
            neibs[y].push_back(make_pair(x, z));
            totallength += z;
        }
        int totalmst = 0;
        int dist[200001];
        for (int i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
            dist[i] = MAX;
        }
        int treesize = 1;
        priority_queue<pair<int, int>>q;
        dist[0] = 0;
        bool intree[200001] = { 0 };
        intree[0] = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < neibs[i].size(); i++) {
            int next = neibs[0][i].first;
            int val = neibs[0][i].second;
            dist[next] = val;
            q.push(make_pair(val, next));
        }
        while (treesize < m) {
            int minnode, mindis = MAX;
            minnode = q.top().second;
            mindis = q.top().first;
            intree[minnode] = true;
            totalmst += mindis;
            treesize++;
            for (int i = 0; i < neibs[minnode].size(); i++) {
                int next = neibs[minnode][i].first;
                int val = neibs[minnode][i].second;
                if (!intree[next] && dist[next] > val + dist[minnode]) {
                    dist[next] = val + dist[minnode];
                    q.push(make_pair(dist[next], next));
                }
            }
        }
        cout << totallength - totalmst << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code or with my Visual Studio?  Thanks for helping me.

Comment: `vector<pair<int, int>>neibs[200001];` Don't put large arrays like that on the stack; stack size is limited. One possible approach is to make it a vector, as in `vector< vector<pair<int, int>> > neibs(200001);`

Comment: Shouldn't you use a debugger and try to monitor your stack?

Comment: The default stack size in MSVC is currently 1MB. You can change this with the `/F` compiler option (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks.aspx - there are several other ways to change this, this is the most common), but as noted by @IgorTandetnik, you might want to rethink your approach to take better advantage of dynamic (heap-based) memory usage by the available STL containers.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik, can't grok your comment. can underlying array of vector be placed on stack.? or what you about.?

Comment: @GreenTree Yes, a (reasonably sized) array of vectors can be placed on the stack. That's not the problem. The problem is that the stack size is limited. Any data structure - whether an array of vectors, an array of something else, or not an array at all - of sufficiently large size would, if placed on the stack, exceed its limits and cause a stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks for helping me!  Now I know that dynamic memory uses heap which is much bigger than static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should allocate both the vectors you use in heap:

```
std::unique_ptr<vector<pair<int, int>>> neibs(new vector<pair<int, int>>[200001]);

std::unique_ptr<priority_queue<pair<int, int>>> q(new priority_queue<pair<int, int>>());
```

Comment: so underlying array of vector can be placed on stack.(?) please, quote the standard.

Comment: @GreenTree *"**[intro.compliance]/(2.1)** If a program contains no violations of the rules in this International Standard, a conforming implementation shall, **within its resource limits**, accept and correctly execute that program."* Emphasis mine. The problem is not in placing an array, specifically, on the stack; the problem is that the program places a large data structure on the stack, exceeding the resource limits of the implementation. The fact that this data structure happens to be an array is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

or try to do something like that

```
template < class... Args >
std::vector< Args... > make_vector ( std::size_t const volatile size )
{ return std::vector< Args... >( size ) ; }
```

and then 
    `auto vec0 = make_vector< int >( 200001 ) ;`

but the safest (only?) way to deal with such optimizations is to switch them off (with compiler options).